# How to check bitfields (SCNetworkReachabilityFlags in particular) for flags in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bit-fields, bitmask

I have a `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` variable and want to check it for particular values, e.g. if the network is reachable via WWAN.

The `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` type is a `typealias` for `UInt32` and the various options are defined as `Int` variables.

Using Objective-C you could do the following:

```
if (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN) {
 // do stuff
}
```

In Swift if I try this:

```
if reachabilityFlags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN {
 // do stuff
}
```

you get a compiler error: `Could not find an overload for '&' that accepts the supplied arguments`.

I've read some other questions where the bitfield options where defined as a `RawOptionSet` struct. This hasn't been done in `SCNetworkReachability`.

How to you check for flags in Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is actually complaining not about the arguments of your flags-check, but about the return value. An `if` statement expects a boolean (or at least something conforming to `Logical`), but the `&` operator for two `Int` values returns an `Int`. You just need a comparison in your `if` statement:

```
let flags = kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable
if 0 != flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable {
    println("flags contains kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable")
}
```

Since `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` and the constants are (strangely) of different types, you'll need to do some casting to make the comparison work:

```
let reachabilityFlags:SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable)
if 0 != reachabilityFlags & SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) {
    println("reachabilityFlags contains kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable")
}
```