# Wrapping libcups C library in Swift

Tags: swift, cups

I am trying to wrap the libcups library https://github.com/apple/cups to be used in my Swift project.

I have tried some of the examples in https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html and they are working fine.

However I am struggling when it comes to wrapping the C code to be used in a Swift project.

I have been searching online on how to wrap C libraries in Swift but has not been able to have much progress.

Here is the C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cups/cups.h>

typedef struct {
    int num_dests;
    cups_dest_t *dests;
} my_user_data_t;

int my_dest_cb(my_user_data_t *user_data, unsigned flags, cups_dest_t *dest) {
    if (flags & CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_REMOVED) {
        user_data->num_dests = cupsRemoveDest(dest->name, dest->instance, user_data->num_dests, &(user_data->dests));
    } else {
        user_data->num_dests = cupsCopyDest(dest, user_data->num_dests, &(user_data->dests));
    }
    return 1;
}

int my_get_dests(cups_ptype_t type, cups_ptype_t mask, cups_dest_t **dests) {
    my_user_data_t user_data = { 0, NULL };

    if (!cupsEnumDests(CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_NONE, 1000, NULL, type, mask, (cups_dest_cb_t)my_dest_cb, &user_data)) {
        cupsFreeDests(user_data.num_dests, user_data.dests);
        *dests = NULL;
        return 0;
    } else {
        *dests = user_data.dests;
        return user_data.num_dests;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cups_dest_t *dests = NULL;
    int num_dests = my_get_dests(0, 0, &dests);
    printf("Destination found: %d\n", num_dests);

    cups_dest_t *dest;
    int i;
    const char *value;

    for (i = num_dests, dest = dests; i > 0; i--, dest++) {
        if (dest->instance == NULL) {
            value = cupsGetOption("printer-info", dest->num_options, dest->options);
            printf("%s (%s)\n", dest->name, value ? value : "No description");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the same thing but in Swift

```
let destinationsCallback: cups_dest_cb_t = { user_data, flags, dest in
    // (void *user_data, unsigned flags, cups_dest_t *dest)
    var userDataPointer = user_data!.assumingMemoryBound(to: my_user_data_t.self).pointee
    var destData = dest!.pointee

    if destData.instance != nil {
        print("\(String(cString: destData.name))/\(String(cString: destData.instance))")
    } else {
        print(String(cString: destData.name))
    }

    if flags == CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_REMOVED {
        userDataPointer.num_dests = cupsRemoveDest(destData.name, destData.instance, userDataPointer.num_dests, &(userDataPointer.dests))
    } else {
        userDataPointer.num_dests = cupsCopyDest(dest, userDataPointer.num_dests, &(userDataPointer.dests))
    }
    return 1
}

func getDestinations(type: UInt32, mask: UInt32, dests: UnsafeMutablePointer<cups_dest_t>) -> Int32 {
    var userData = my_user_data_t(num_dests: 0, dests: nil)

    if cupsEnumDests(UInt32(CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_NONE), 1000, nil, type, mask, destinationsCallback, &userData) != 1 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return userData.num_dests
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the userData to return the correct value which I am assuming is due to the way I handle the pointers.

Greatly appreciate if I am able to get some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the best way to work with such C libraries in Swift is to work with them in Objective-C. Nevertheless, the main issue seems to be that you are not writing back changes to userData, that's why you always get your initial value. You need to update it in your callback like this

```
let userDataPointer = user_data!.assumingMemoryBound(to: my_user_data_t.self)
var userData = userDataPointer.pointee
...
// make some changes to userData

userDataPointer.pointee = userData

return 1
```

Also there seems to be some differences between your C code and the Swift one, like checking flags with 'flags == CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_REMOVED' which, in general, is incorrect way to check flags, and comparing result of cupsEnumDests with 1 when in the original code you check that result is not 0.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer my userData is now updated. 
Any suggestions on how I can check the value of the flags? Base on the documentation cupsEnumDests returns an int and flags is unsigned.

Comment: @hweiguang I mean you need to use '&' to check that flag is set like in your C code, the could several flags set at once and then checking for equality will fail. Something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24557094/381333

Comment: Cool I will make the changes as per your suggestions thanks!